# How do I replace duplicate whitespaces in a String in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Say I have a string: `"Test    me"`.

how do I convert it to: `"Test me"`?

I've tried using:

```
string?.replace("\\s+", " ")
```

but it appears that `\\s` is an illegal escape in Kotlin.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

[`replace` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) in Kotlin has overloads for either raw string and regex patterns.

```
"Test  me".replace("\\s+", " ")
```

This replaces raw string `\s+`, which is the problem.

```
"Test  me".replace("\\s+".toRegex(), " ")
```

This line replaces multiple whitespaces with a single space. 
Note the explicit [`toRegex()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-regex.html) call, which makes a `Regex` from a `String`, thus specifying the overload with `Regex` as pattern.

There's also an overload which allows you to produce the replacement from the matches. For example, to replace them with the first whitespace encountered, use this:

```
"Test\n\n  me".replace("\\s+".toRegex()) { it.value[0].toString() }
```

---

By the way, if the operation is repeated, consider moving the pattern construction out of the repeated code for better efficiency:

```
val pattern = "\\s+".toRegex()

for (s in strings)
    result.add(s.replace(pattern, " "))
```

Comment: With regex it is sometimes nice to use `"""` instead of `"` for the regex string so that you do not have to escape the contents of the regex.