# Replacement with Capture Groups in Kotlin differs from Java

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

Say I'm trying to convert a string from camelCase to snake case. In Java, I would do the following:

```
str.replaceAll("([a-z]+)([A-Z]+)", "$1\\_$2");
```

However, this doesn't work with Kotlin. The string remains unchanged.

```
str.replace("([a-z]+)([A-Z]+)", "$1\\_$2");
```

What is the correct way to do replacement with capture groups in Kotlin?

Comment: Doesn't Kotlin have the feature that you can always fall back to any class in the standard Java platform?

Comment: Not Kotlin dev but based on few minute research maybe you are facing same problem as [How do I replace duplicate whitespaces in a String in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37070352), which would mean you would need something along `str.replace("([a-z]+)([A-Z]+)".toRegex(), "$1\\_$2");`

Comment: Maybe kotlin doesn't change the string but returns a new one with the desired format